# Echo highlighted warning in one line

Tags: vimscript, highlight, echo

I found from the vim's manual that we can echo colored text by the following command:

```
:echohl WarningMsg | echo "Warnging" | echohl None | echo ":Some warning"
```

which will highlight the string `Warning` and keep `:Some warning` in default color. My problem is that this will display the results in two lines, is there any way to display them in one line?

Comment: See [how-to-change-the-command-line-status-message-color-and-font](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/26278/how-to-change-the-command-line-status-message-color-and-font)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

```
function! EchoWarning(msg)
  echohl WarningMsg
  echo "Warning"
  echohl None
  echon ': ' a:msg
endfunction

call EchoWarning('test')
```

This defined a simple function that you can call with the warning message as the argument.

As you see, the key is the `echon` command, which is similar to an `echo` except it does not add a newline at the end.

Comment: how can i specify other colors? such as `green`.

Comment: You can define a new highlight group (see `:help :highlight`) and use it instead of `WarningMsg`.