# How to change the command line status message color and font?

Tags: command-line, color, echo

I would like to change the color of part of the command line, the stuff that's `echo`'d from vim scripts. I know it can be different since when your search hits the bottom it prints a message in red text.

I tried to echo vt100 color codes but they were escaped instead. For example, `:echo "\033[0;32m some text"` just prints those characters literally (except the escape, which is shown as `^[`)

Ideally I'd like to find a solution that works in both vim-gtk as well as the terminal UI.

Comment: Try `:help echohl`

Comment: I am pretty sure, you can do this starting from 8.2.258 and using the `echoraw()` function, like this: `call echoraw("\033[38;5;124m")|echo "red text"`

Comment: hi @ChristianBrabandt How to revert normal font? Please. I cannot find it in `:h echoraw`. Maybe `:call echoraw("\x1b[41m") | echo " red text" | call echoraw(" \x1b[0m") | echo "unformmated text"` isn't the way, is it?

Comment: `echon` works weirdly with `echoraw()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try combination of `:h echohl` and `:h echon`:

```
:echohl Statement | echon "Hello " | echohl Identifier | echon "World" | echohl None | echon "!!!"
```

`echohl` will apply highlight group to the next `echo`, `echon` or `echomsg`, but if you want to apply highlighting to a *part* of your message you should use `echon`.

[image]

To have all your message in one color, use `echo` or `echomsg`:

```
:echohl Todo | echo "Hello World!!!" | echohl None
```

[image]

To define your own colors use `:h :hi`

```
:hi MyColor guifg=#00ff00 ctermfg=green
:echohl MyColor | echo "Hello World!!!" | echohl None
```

[image]

**You can not change font of the messages**, but I might be wrong.

Comment: Well you may be able to italicize or bold it

Comment: @D.BenKnoble but can we change it from Consolas to Liberation Mono?

Comment: Doubtful—I think that’s handled by the emulator

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks! I was trying to Google for an answer for this initially, but searching "vim change command line color" turned up a lot of results about setting syntax highlighting and color schemes instead

Comment: See also [defined a simple function that you can call with the warning message as the argument](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13390/29452). Summary: `function! EchoWarning(msg);
  echohl WarningMsg;
  echo "Warning";
  echohl None;
  echon ': ' a:msg;
endfunction;

call EchoWarning('test')` (copy-paste-remove semicolon-indent)

Comment: Define highlight variables (like `:hi MyColor guifg=#00ff00 ctermfg=green`) AFTER load colorscheme plugin in `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: i have this: `hi TerminalGreenColor guifg=#6bd676` and this line `echon " -- [ " | echohl Identifier | echon "init.vim" | echohl None | echon " ] reloaded " | echohl TerminalGreenColor | echon "successfully" | echohl None | echon " -- "` and its not working properly. it only colors for "init.vim" with `Identifier` color and `TerminalGreenColor` its not working. what am i missing? 

i put that long line into a function and i called that function like so: `nnoremap <C-R> :source $init_vim_path<CR> :call EchoInitVimReloadedSuccessfully()<CR>`.